# Flow Type refinement by checking for existing properties

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

Here is the example given below in [try flowtype](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqBLAtsAMhgO2AGEIBXKAZ2DWVQF44BvAKDjgBMBDGYALjiUYUQgHMANG04QiAgEYQIAG2BcCk9gGMewUdEQB9AlxwChIghJYBfANwsWoSLAR102PIRI9aKOI1Z2bl4zYTENaVk4BWVVdSkoNQBrA0IDAHdgYCSBAjIsOWAoSTsHJ2h4JD9MHHwiAGUYHkpfBmYpYP5BMMsImA9KMDVQi1EbexZNGSFODEGlLkQa4CUvAEleLH84AAoMTYFlupJyKho3AB93Wq9iH0vrzwammBa6cTgMXPzCqABKfwAPna7AwADNdvtgFgAHTaXh6KCGYw4AGBdhwKDAGAUAi7KQYz6bGFgBaIVZCIwmYAfAkYqGw+G6fRUnB0v72djWOAraifCF7YmJAgpNKZbJoulYnFQPE7OmgoXJVIEDJZJLszlwbm81Do9jS3GQ4n9HCDNQcqTWcZAA)

```
export type TimeLineCourseType = {
    date: string,
    done: boolean,
    category_name: string,
};

export type TimeLineCatType = {
    date: string,
    done: boolean,
    rank_in_week: number,
};

export type TimeLineStatsType = {
    date: string,
    timespan: string
};

const displayTimelineItem = (item: TimeLineCourseType | TimeLineCatType | TimeLineStatsType, i: number) => {
    if (item.category_name) {
        return (
            item.playlist_name,
            item.category_name
        );
    } else if (item.rank_in_week) {
        return (
            item.rank_in_week
        );
    } else {
        return (item.timespan);
    }
};
```

It is clear from the if else blocks, that the item in each can only be of one specific type, not all three. Yet I get flow errors. Also using `hasOwnProperty` does not help. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You haven't declared this attrs in your types:  playlist_name, category_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this effect, called a [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) in Flow, by either adding a common key to all types and refining based on its value or switching to using [exact types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types).

here's an example using a `type` key to refine:

```
export type TimeLineCourseType = {
  date: string,
  done: boolean,
  category_name: string,
  type: 'TimeLineCourseType',
};

export type TimeLineCatType = {
  date: string,
  done: boolean,
  rank_in_week: number,
  type: 'TimeLineCatType',
};

export type TimeLineStatsType = {
  date: string,
  timespan: string
  type: 'TimeLineStatsType',
};

const displayTimelineItem = (item: TimeLineCourseType | TimeLineCatType | TimeLineStatsType, i: number) => {
  if (item.type === 'TimeLineCourseType') {
    return (
      item.playlist_name, 
      item.category_name
    );
  } else if (item.type === 'TimeLineCatType') {
    return (
      item.rank_in_week
    );
  } else {
    return (item.timespan);
  }
};
```

or you can continue with your approach by making the types ["exact" objects](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) with pipes, `{| |}` inside the curly brackets:

```
export type TimeLineCourseType = {|
  date: string,
  done: boolean,
  category_name: string,
|};

export type TimeLineCatType = {|
  date: string,
  done: boolean,
  rank_in_week: number,
|};

export type TimeLineStatsType = {|
  date: string,
  timespan: string
|};

const displayTimelineItem = (item: TimeLineCourseType | TimeLineCatType | TimeLineStatsType, i: number) => {
  if (item.category_name) {
    return (
      item.playlist_name, 
      item.category_name
    );
  } else if (item.rank_in_week) {
    return (
      item.rank_in_week
    );
  } else if (item.timespan) {
    return (item.timespan);
  }
};
```

The pipes make this work because due to [width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/) in Flow, objects are allowed to have "extra" keys. Flow doesn't work in your code because, for example, it's valid for a `TimeLineStatsType` to have a `rank_in_week` key. Flow can't refine the type by checking for the existence of `rank_in_week`.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I "simply" converted all my types into exact objects using the pipe notation. I am confused why this is not the default mode though...

Comment: I agree typing those pipes over and over again gets tiresome, and it's easy to forget them. Like all of Flow, its type system was designed to be applied incrementally to a codebase. I imagine enabling extra attributes initially made it easier to adopt Flow. It would be great if exact objects could be enabled via .flowconfig for an entire project.

Comment: Strangely enough, the Flow team announced today (2018-10-16) they are planning on making Objects "exact" by default in Flow. They have a detailed timeline for how it will be enabled: https://medium.com/flow-type/on-the-roadmap-exact-objects-by-default-16b72933c5cf