# Flow doesn't understand checks for null or undefined

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Now I'm working with Flow types generated by [Apollo Codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling). It's very useful tool, but all types are "maybe" ones. And now I have the next problem: please, consider very minified and simple example (link to [Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwAqOuAjGALxgDeAPmGMMGADwC0YuAHgIYC22MfHChgAYvASsseMAHNcAO1wAnbulwATMACNMYAILY4MeGADCcDbnkLU9bMrjYA-AC4wzgM7plASwWyqDQAvnZgGMSExABMFNQMTGwcPPyCYMJgvHriiFLEYQ5O7t5+Aaih9KhQAK4KAMbovnAKOtzKABSY7kR40QCU7gBucL5aVGF1zZ7GuAB08LKds4XYfeWoVbUNTS1QcHDtnN3EJANgw6PUYb4ih2AAZPdgnMuO2A9P0rgZLysU5JQAOQlfyyQF9eKMFjsACSgN4YB8mFBiLgYDqAAtcHUANaIrFgABEnEJYDasmqvEU6DC9G0bUOa3ooVCVX27SoYBW7kBWJMcEBYGCfSAA)):

```
/* @flow */
type Type1 = {|  // <- example of Flow-type generated by Apollo Codegen
  prop?: ?string
|}

type Type2 = { // <- example of my Flow-type
  prop: string
}

function bar(y: Type2): void {
  console.log(y.prop)
}

function foo(x: Type1): void {
  if (x && x.prop && typeof x.prop === 'string') { // <- I'm trying to check the "x" argument
    bar(x)
  }
}

foo({ prop: 'hello' })
```

Flow doesn't understand my checks and shows the error because of `null` or `undefined`. How to manage that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work as a type refinement is that your check can pass for both `Type1` and `Type2`. Flow does the conditional check, but the check can pass for a value of `Type1`, so the conditional does not refine the type of `x` at all. Then inside the conditional it sees you trying to pass a value of `Type1` to `Type2`.

To understand Flow's type refinements, it's important to remember that Flow doesn't carry additional refinement data on a variable other than that variable's type. [Here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBiccYAvGAN6phhQCWeMAJgFxgB2ArgLYBGeAE5gAPmADOGQfQ4BzMKgC+AbnTZ8YAEIBDYRWq0GTNp14DBS1aihcOAYwz04HMADdtMeswAUWdsTgASjB2bn4hKhoweigwb3U8OFisADojFnIyCgByMPNs4INaMEE8DC5BF1T05jAAajAARlVaRSio0vLKsAAGVTbrWwcnFxl3Tx8-IhJg0LMIopi4hKSwasYMrJy8oQLI4pKyipdtZmYAFThCDcnAlrA22g6j7r6ldBt7R2cwU4urm6+dg6QSzUzhYRFTrHNZpG71JrKBSKIA) is an example which is similar to yours, but without optional fields. In the `valid` function, we check the type of `y.field`, and then use `y.field` once we know its type. In the `invalid` function, we check the type of `y.field`, and then try to use `y`. But the type refinement didn't change the type of `y` here, only of `y.field`, so we get a type error.

As a counterpoint, [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBCAhgF5gC8YA3qmGLMQOYBcYGATgK54A0dDAJZ4YAEzYA7LgFsARng6oAvgG502fGACKXAB6UaAxqwbEYAZz5HhYtuc6CJTZWtRQuEgMYZBcCQwAKUjYScgAfbT0ASjBJGXkOQ3pBKDAggDpjGNp6eg48DC4Of2JRUQAVOFCgqLV6JQEBfMLisAAGNQa3D29fErLK6uCiMmymgqL-UkybUTAAajAARk6gA) is an example where we do a type refinement based on the value of a field. What's important to note is that inside of the `f` function, the variable `z` has the type `Baz | Qux`, and that our refinement is on a field which does not overlap between those two. In this case the refinement turns the type `Baz | Qux` into the type `Baz`, and we can call our second function without error.

To get around this limitation in your case, we need to break down the value `x` and put the field that we're refining into its own variable. Then, once we know the type of this variable, we create a value that we know has type `Type2` and pass that into the desired function. [Here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqueAjGALxgDeAPmGMMGADwC0YeAHgIYC2OGAThQwAMXgI22fGADmeAHZ4ATjwx4AJmABGWMAEEccGPDABhOJrwLFqBjhVwcAfgBcYFwGcMKgJaKcqi0AL4A3PZgmCREJABMlDSMzOycvAJCYCJgfPoSiNIkkY7OHj7+gajhkahQAK6KAMYYfnCKujwqABRYHsT4cQCUHgBucH7a1JGNbV4meAB08HI9CyU4g1Xo9U0tbWBQcHBdXH0kpMNgYxM007MYSetgIYlcEQx+ol0yeNlPFACwABycoBORAwa3BgMHSdLrUMBPEKDd7PLa1I7wxFOHAeIEACzwpjgQOeKKAA) is the most direct way of doing that.

Because this kind of thing comes up often, I have a pattern of creating "conversion" functions to turn potentially unclean data into clean data, so that other functions don't have to bother with the complexity of refinements. In this case I would do so like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgAqueAjGALxgDeAPmGMMGADwC0YeAHgIYC2OGAThQwAMXgI22fGADmeAHZ4ATjwx4AJmABGWMAEEccGPDABhOJrwLFqBjhVwcAfgBcYFwGcMKgJaKcqi0AL4A3PZgmCREJABMlDSMzOycvAJCYCJgfPoSiNIkkY7OHj7+gajhkahQAK6KAMYYfnCKujwqABRYHsT4cQCUHgBucH7a1JGNbV4meAB08HI9CyU4g1Xo9U0tbWBQcHBdXH0kpMNgYxM007MYYFwJVDOKI6oY-WRfcSeDEQw-KITkMOt0nv8trUGs1Wu1Xu8VJ9zj8Tmd8BcwOi8Al6Io6qZbgxXj4kuswCFElwAVFAcCZHhsuSKCywABycoBORswZEhhgFR4DB1FTtahgcnVBghGoMQXC0VgfGmCIy2pHLri9YeNkACzwpjgbIp-yAA).

This pattern of factoring out conversion functions can also be very helpful when sanitizing deeply nested data, or converting nested objects from type `mixed` into known types. It is much easier to create a conversion function for a large type by combining conversion objects for small types than it is to write one from scratch.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. I'll try implements all these ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you're refining the type of the property `prop`, you're not refining `x`. Refinement in flow can only really be used for top-level types. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50872258/flow-type-refinement-by-checking-for-existing-properties) for some alternate strategies.